# Speeding up AMANDA within the backup window

Tags: backup, performance, amanda

I'm running AMANDA with an LTO-6 drive spooling off a local RAID array. The backups are beginning to take longer than the eight hour backup window. Are there any config options to cut some time off the backups (The disks are spiking near 100% utilization for minutes at a time so the upgrade would likely involve a faster RAID array. Possibly more RAM). Other than disks, I don't think the hardware is bottlenecking; CPU utilization is 30% and under, RUNQ is 8 or under (16 core system) and disk swap use is 60Kb and under.

[image]

Here is my config. I'm not sure the netusage parameter does anything since these are all local files to the drive. Any obvious config changes to speed things up? Would `inparallel` help with more RAM?

```
inparallel   6           
dumporder    "sssS"        
taperalgo    first            
displayunit  "m"            
netusage     600 Kbps         
dumpcycle    1 week s             
runtapes     1                     
runspercycle 1          
tapecycle    17 tapes
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about your setup?  Is this AMANDA app just backing up the one host's RAID to the LTO-6?  Is it backing up multiple AMANDA clients?  Is there a holding disk defined?  What part of the process is taking 8 hours? Talking to all the clients, or just reading the RAID partitions and waiting on the LTO-6?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it got sorted out. The configs have been dragged through many tape/drive upgrades over the past 10 years and at some point compression was enabled on both the tape drive *and* through `gzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your question regarding Amanda.

While backing up data to Tapes, it is always recommended not to use the software compression. Most Tape drives have hardware compression available and this normally provides good compression ratio at fast rates. Enabling both software and hardware compression would delay your backups significantly.

If you have any other questions, feel free to let us know.

Zmanda Support

Answer (score 1):

Compression was enabled on both the drive and via amanda config. After disabling amanda compression things improved enough that dump time vastly decreased to 2:43 now.